# Why does the css border not appear all the way around my html image?

Tags: html, css, border

I have an html page `services.html` with two images on it. One image, `placeholder.jpeg` lies partly on top of another image `physiotherapy-06.peg` and I have applied css styling to the `placeholder.jpeg` image with `border: 10px solid gray;`. But only part of this image has its border rendered, the part that doesn't lie on the `physiotherapy-06.jpeg` image. How do I get the border to render fully around the edge of the `placeholder.jpeg` image?

Here is my `services.html` file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" /> -->
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <title>JU Physiotherapy - Services</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <header class="services-header">
    <img class="services-title-image" src="images/physiotherapy-06.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class="services-logo-image" src="images/placeholder.jpeg" alt="">
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my `styles.css` file;

```
.services-header {
    border: none;
}

.services-title-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.services-logo-image {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid gray;
    margin: -15% auto 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result;
[image: Screenshot of border problem]

Comment: try position:relative to image

Comment: ...or `isolation:isolate`

Comment: add position:relative to this class .services-logo-image

Comment: Yes! position: relative works! Thanks!